Sanity GROQ Filter Query
i would like some help with GROQ. So I have a document called careers which has 2 fields. department and listings. These 2 fields are documents of their own so they are referenced within careers.
department has one field -> name.
listings is an array which has the following fields -> title, slug, type, location
I am trying to write a query that filters the careers based on a listings slug. So for example if i pass the following slug "frontend-engineer", my filter query should return the appropriate listing based on the slug.
This is the original query which gets all careers and all listings within them.
*[_type == "careers"]{
  department -> {
    name
  },
  listings[] -> {
    title,
    'slug': slug.current,
    type,
    location
  }
}

This results in
"result": [
    {
      "department": {
        "name": "Engineering"
      },
      "listings": [
        {
          "title": "Frontend Engineer",
          "slug": "frontend-engineer",
          "type": "FULL-TIME",
          "location": "FCT - Abuja"
        },
        {
          "title": "Backend Engineer",
          "slug": "backend-engineer",
          "type": "PART-TIME",
          "location": "Anambra"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

I tried the following query but for some reason it's not filtering. I currently stomped. I checked the sanity docs but I can't find anything that helps.
*[_type == "careers" && "frontend-engineer" in listings[]->slug.current]{
  department -> {
    name
  },
  listings[] -> {
    title,
    'slug': slug.current,
    type,
    location
  }
}


